# Subset sublists of nested list by vector condition

Tags: r, subset, nested-lists

I have a nested list `list1`:

```
list1 <- list(Alpha = structure(list(sample_0 = c(3, NA, 7, 9, 2),
                                     sample_1 = c(NA, 3, 5, 4, NA),
                                     sample_2 = c(7, 3, 5, NA, NA)),
                                row.names = c(NA, -5L),
                                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")),
              Beta = structure (list(sample_0 = c(2, 9, NA, 3, 7),
                                     sample_1 = c(3, 7, 9, 3, NA),
                                     sample_2 = c(4, 2, 6, 4, 6)),
                                row.names = c(NA, -5L),
                                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")),
              Gamma = structure(list(sample_0 = c(NA, NA, 4, 6, 3),
                                     sample_1 = c(3, 5, 3, NA, 2)),
                                row.names = c(NA, -5L),
                                class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")),
              Delta = structure(list(sample_0 = c(3, NA, 7, 9, 2),
                                     sample_1 = c(3, 8, 5, 4, 9)),
                                     row.names = c(NA, -5L),
                                     class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")))
```

I needed to change one Column to a factor level, as follows (is there a more elegant way to do that than using a for loop?):

```
for (i in names(list1)) {
  list1[[i]]$sample_1 <- list1[[i]]$sample_1 %>% as.numeric() %>% 
    cut(breaks=c(0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10),
        labels=c("-", "+", "++", "+++", "++++"), right = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE)
 }
```

I now would like to keep only the sublists that contain at least level "+++" (or "++++") in sample_1...

```
sapply(sapply(list1, `[`, "sample_1"), unique)
$Alpha.sample_1
[1] <NA> +    ++  
Levels: - + ++ +++ ++++

$Beta.sample_1
[1] +    +++  ++++ <NA>
Levels: - + ++ +++ ++++

$Gamma.sample_1
[1] +    ++   <NA> -   
Levels: - + ++ +++ ++++

$Delta.sample_1
[1] +    +++  ++   ++++
Levels: - + ++ +++ ++++
```

... and all the other elements of the same sublist in a new list2. The desired result would look as follows:

```
list1
$Beta
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  sample_0 sample_1 sample_2
     <dbl> <fct>       <dbl>
1        2 +               4
2        9 +++             2
3       NA ++++            6
4        3 +               4
5        7 NA              6
    
$Delta
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  sample_0 sample_1
     <dbl> <fct>   
1        3 +       
2       NA +++     
3        7 ++      
4        9 +       
5        2 ++++
```

I believe I would have to convert the vector to as.integer, but I can't come up with the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define what you want to do in a function `myFun`, use it in `lapply` and subset the result for `nrow` > 0.

```
myFun <- \(x) {
  x$sample_1  <- with(x, cut(sample_1, breaks=c(0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10),
                             labels=c("-", "+", "++", "+++", "++++"), 
                             right=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE))
  subset(x, sample_1 %in% c("+++", "++++"))
}
    
res <- lapply(list1, myFun)
res[sapply(res, nrow) > 0]
# $Beta
#   sample_0 sample_1 sample_2
# 2        9      +++        2
# 3       NA     ++++        6
# 
# $Delta
#   sample_0 sample_1
# 2       NA      +++
# 5        2     ++++
#
```

### Edit

To split the list elements into sublists at the threshold, you may use `split` in the function. We may also split at the underlying integer, i.e. `as.numeric(x$sample_1)`.

```
myFun2 <- \(x) {
  x$sample_1 <- with(x, cut(sample_1, breaks=c(0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10), 
                            labels=c("-", "+", "++", "+++", "++++"), 
                            right=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE))
  split(x, as.numeric(x$sample_1) > 4)
}

lapply(list1, myFun2)
# $Alpha
# $Alpha$`FALSE`
# sample_0 sample_1 sample_2
# 2       NA        +        3
# 3        7       ++        5
# 4        9        +       NA
# 
# 
# $Beta
# $Beta$`FALSE`
# sample_0 sample_1 sample_2
# 1        2        +        4
# 2        9      +++        2
# 4        3        +        4
# 
# $Beta$`TRUE`
# sample_0 sample_1 sample_2
# 3       NA     ++++        6
# 
# 
# $Gamma
# $Gamma$`FALSE`
# sample_0 sample_1
# 1       NA        +
#   2       NA       ++
#   3        4        +
#   5        3        -
#   
#   
#   $Delta
# $Delta$`FALSE`
# sample_0 sample_1
# 1        3        +
#   2       NA      +++
#   3        7       ++
#   4        9        +
#   
#   $Delta$`TRUE`
# sample_0 sample_1
# 5        2     ++++
```

Comment: One question:  Is there a solution using the numeric value for the levels too (instead of specifying them by using c("+++", "++++")? Say I have many more levels, ordered by manitude (like the "-" to "++++" magnitude in my example), and I want to set the cutoff at the numeric level of a factor?

Comment: @Gnueghoidune Something like  `lapply(list1, function(x) x[x$sample_1 > 5, ])`?

Comment: Exactly, but preferably after already having cut sample_1 into factors, then again transferring to a new list only containing all elements of a sublist, in which the numeric value of a factor level is above a certain threshhold (but keeping the other factor levels too).
(I'm not sure if I am making myself clear here ^^)

Comment: @Gnueghoidune Then `lapply(list1, function(x) x[as.numeric(x$sample_1) > 4, ])` after `cut` perhaps.

Comment: You're fast! This works, however, it drops the factor levels <4, which I would like to keep too (and preferably, the output is in factor levels again)

Comment: @Gnueghoidune I see, the NAs are ugly. Try `lapply(list1, subset, as.numeric(sample_1) > 4)`, you actually could use any algebra then.

Comment: The desired output would not drop the factor levels <4 but keep them. Only check, if one of them is >4, if yes, copy the whole element (along with the others of the sublist), ideally preserving factor levels after having cut the element.
(greetings from Bern)

Comment: @Gnueghoidune Ah sorry in the function of course use `subset(x, as.numeric(sample_1) > 4)` as second line, no `levels()` are dropped.

Comment: lapply(list1, subset(x, as.numeric(sample_1) > 4), as.numeric(sample_1) > 4)
throws
Error in subset(x, as.numeric(sample_1) > 4) : object 'x' not found

Comment: @Gnueghoidune No, change `myFun <- \(x) {x$sample_1 <- with(x, cut(sample_1, breaks=c(0, 2, 4, 5, 8, 10), labels=c("-", "+", "++", "+++", "++++"), right=TRUE, na.rm=TRUE));subset(x, as.numeric(sample_1) > 4)}`

Comment: If I run the function, afterwards applying it to every element with 
res <- lapply(list1, myFun)
it still drops any factor below "++++"

Comment: @Gnueghoidune Well, have you tried `> 3`?

Comment: I have. I guess I didn't express myself clarly; I want the levels below the threshold (>3 or >4) to be preserved as well. Imagine I have a list of students and the "-" to "++++" symbols represent test grades. I would like to have a new list only containing students having achieved a test result of at least "+++" (>3). However, I need the values under the score to be preserved as well (so "-" for example should be transferred to the new list too) so that I can analyze all of the values of each student, for example in a time series. (Maybe I should open up a new question for this)

Comment: @Gnueghoidune Do you actually want two lists, one with those above and one with those below the threshold, i.e. the original list split into two sublists?

Comment: That would be phenomenal!

Comment: @Gnueghoidune Really no problem, please see edit. Hope this works :)

Comment: You're a real hero. Thanks a lot!
Just for reproducibility for others, you might want to name the function myFun2 too, same as you apply afterwards to list1)

Comment: You're welcome @Gnueghoidune, glad it finally worked! Made the edit, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A little function + sapply can help:

```
contains_3plus <- function(greek_letter){
    ("+++" %in% greek_letter$sample_1) | ("++++" %in% greek_letter$sample_1)
}


list1[which(sapply(list1, contains_3plus))]

# $Beta
# # A tibble: 5 × 3
# sample_0 sample_1 sample_2
# <dbl> <fct>       <dbl>
#   1        2 +               4
# 2        9 +++             2
# 3       NA ++++            6
# 4        3 +               4
# 5        7 NA              6
# 
# $Delta
# # A tibble: 5 × 2
# sample_0 sample_1
# <dbl> <fct>   
#   1        3 +       
#   2       NA +++     
#   3        7 ++      
#   4        9 +       
#   5        2 ++++
```